# Hacer Binding al Valor de un ComboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding, mvvm

Mi problema es que estoy tratando de hacer binding entre un `ComboBox` y una propiedad tipo `string` en viewModel, pero no consigo realizarlo

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=OResultado, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Anomalia"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Retiro"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Retiro con Anomalia"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Conforme"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Traté con `SelectedItem` y `SelectedValue`, `SelectedIndex`pero me arroja solo el índice del `ComboBoxItem` seleccionado. Traté de hacer un `Converter` pero no logré que arrojara el resultado esperado.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario seleccione un item  del `ComboBox`
el valor `Content` del item  se asigne a la propiedad de tipo `string OResultado` de mi viewModel.

Comment: Es decir quieres que la propiedad `SelectedItem` sea asignada por Binding?

Comment: @JuanK Edite la pregunta para que quede claro lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este caso hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero la forma que menos trabajo trae es poblando el ComboBox dinámicamente en lugar de con valores estáticos.

Esto se logra creando la lista de opciones en el `ViewModel` y haciendo `Binding` con el `ItemsSource` del `ComboBox`.

### viewmodel

puedes obtener BindableBase aquí: [Apps, Binding, INotifyPropertyChanged y BindableBase | XAML | C#](https://juank.io/apps-binding-inotifypropertychanged-bindablebase-xaml-c/) , he establecido el valor de `OResultado= "Conforme"`.

Adicionalmente he realizado el truco de la inicialización perezosa con el llamado a las propiedades para poder crear la instancia del `viewmodel` desde el `xaml`

```
using App3.Util;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace App3.ViewModels
{
    public class MainAppVM : BindableBase
    {
        private bool _initialized = false;
        private object _lockject = new object();

        public ObservableCollection<string> _listaOpciones;
        public ObservableCollection<string> ListaOpciones
        {
            get
            {   Initialize();
                return _listaOpciones;}
            set { SetProperty(ref _listaOpciones, value); }
        }

        private string _oResultado;
        public string OResultado
        {
            get
            {   Initialize();
                return _oResultado; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _oResultado, value); }
        }


        public void Initialize()
        {
            lock (_lockject)
            {
                if (!_initialized)
                {
                    _initialized = true;
                    _listaOpciones = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                    _listaOpciones.Add("Anomalia");
                    _listaOpciones.Add("Retiro");
                    _listaOpciones.Add("Retiro con Anomalia");
                    _listaOpciones.Add("Conforme");

                    _oResultado = "Conforme";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML

ya teniendo el viewModel entonces lo agregas en tu `xaml` como `DataContext`

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainAppVM/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

y luego hacer binding del `ItemsSource` con `ListaOpciones` que es la propiedad expuesta en el ViewModel, de una vez entonces asignas `SelectedItem` para hacer binding con `OResultado` en `TwoWay Mode`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ListaOpciones}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding OResultado,  Mode=TwoWay}" >
</ComboBox>
```

Recuerda agregar la referencia al namespace del viewmodel (línea 5 ).

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:vm="using:App3.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainAppVM/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox x:Name="combo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ListaOpciones}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding OResultado,  Mode=TwoWay}" >
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Esto es Todo!

Y como siempre les digo, hay que aprender Binding, te recomiendo el

### [video curso de XAML especialmente capítulos 5,7,8](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcSxbpIm61W7YOZh8WLi-qRjTmjrBj5wE)